# Passport login-session errors

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport-local

I have written a code in node.js for login and sign up pages using mongoose. The method used for authentication is passport. But I'm getting error 400 bad request for sign-up page and failed to serialize user into session error for login page.

Here's my code regarding the same.

```
const express=require('express');
const bodyparser=require('body-parser');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const https=require('https');
const session=require('express-session');
const passport=require('passport');
const passportLocalMongoose=require('passport-local-mongoose');


const app=express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');


app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(session({
  secret: 'My little secret of football tactics.',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/bankDB" , {useUnifiedTopology:true, useNewUrlParser: true 
});

mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

const bankschema=new mongoose.Schema({
  username:{type:String},
  email:{type:String,unique:true},
  password1:String,
  balance:{type:Number,default:0},
  versionKey: false
});

 bankschema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

bankschema.path('email').validate(async function(email){
const count= await mongoose.models.User.countDocuments({email})
return !count
},'Email-id already exists')

var User=mongoose.model("User",bankschema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.get("/singup.html",  function(req, res){
 res.render("singup");
});
app.get("/login.html",  function(req, res){
 res.render("login");
});
app.get("/",  function(req, res){
 res.render("front");
});
app.get("/next.html",  function(req, res){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
   res.render("next");
  }
  else{
   res.redirect("/login.html");
  }
});



app.post("/singup.html", function(req, res){
  User.register({email:req.body.email,username:req.body.username}, req.body.password1, 
function(err,user){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    res.render('singup');
  }else{

    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        console.log("success");
        res.render("next");
       });
     }
  });


});


app.post('/login.html', function(req, res){
 const user=new User({
  email:req.body.email,
  password1:req.body.password1
 });

 req.login(user, function(err){
   if(err){
    console.log(err);
   }
   else{
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
      console.log("success");
      res.render("next");
   });
 }
});
});
```

Here in signup, the passport.authenticate function is not being executed and I'm not getting why. It's saying bad request every time I try to sign up but the data entered is getting stored in the mongodb.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

In the password.authenticate function inside your `app.post("/singup.html")`, you have redirect to `res.redirect("/next.html")` instead of `res.render("next")`.
This is because after authenticating your user, the `app.get("/next.html")` has to check if its authenticated and for that reason, you need to direct to the `"/next.html"` rather than rendering it as it contradicts the meaning of check validation inside the route. Try this and get back if there are any problems

Comment: Yes I tried using res.redirect method several times but the bug I figured out is it is not going inside the password.authenticate function. To check this I had used the console.log method inside the passport.authenticate but it is not getting executed. Its saying that error 400 bad request. The conclusion was passport.authenticate function is not getting executed and I'm not getting why.

Comment: Do a check up of your existing users, and when you are calling them in a route, console.log the values. It is possible that the data u sent in the backend doesn't exist or you may have done a typo error in terms of the fields. 400 erros are client side, when they want something that doesn't exist due to a typo in your backend.